# mapping many-to-many with interfaces

Tags: c#, nhibernate, interface, many-to-many, nhibernate-mapping

I've searched a lot the web, but doesn't find the right solution for my problem.

Basicly I am trying to create a many-to-many relationship with properties, but as the title says it should work with interfaces instead of normal classes.

these are my two interfaces in the relationship:

```
public interface IFaq  
{  
     IList<IFaqTagReference> FaqTagReferences { get; set; }  
     ...
}

public interface ITag
{  
     IList<IFaqTagReference> FaqTagReference { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

and the third interface which specifies the relationship

```
public interface IFaqTagReference  
{  
     IFaq Faq { get; set; }  
     ITag Tag { get; set; }  
}
```

In the nhibernate mapping i try it that way (normally each element got properties, but its just the relationship which is not working):

```
var mapper = new ConventionModelMapper();  
mapper.Class<Faq>(map =>  
                  {
                     map.Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));
                     map.Set(x => x.FaqTagReferences,
                             db =>
                             {
                                 db.Key(km =>
                                        {
                                            km.Column("FaqId");
                                            km.NotNullable(true);
                                        });                            
                                 db.Table("FaqTagReferences");
                                 db.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                                 db.Inverse(true);
                             }, 
                             r => r.OneToMany(m => m.Class(typeof(FaqTagReference)))    
                             );
                   });

mapper.Class<Tag>(map =>
                 {   
                     map.Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));                 
                     map.Set(x => x.FaqTagReferences,
                             db =>
                             {
                                  db.Key(km =>
                                         {
                                              km.Column("TagId");
                                              km.NotNullable(true);
                                         });
                                  db.Table("FaqTagReferences");
                                  db.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                                  db.Inverse(true);
                             }, 
                             r => r.OneToMany(m => { m.Class(typeof(FaqTagReference)); })
                             );
                 });

mapper.Class<FaqTagReference>(map =>
                         {
                            map.Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));
                            map.ManyToOne(x => x.Faq, db => { db.Column("FaqId"); db.Class(typeof(Faq)); });
                            map.ManyToOne(x => x.Tag, db => { db.Column("TagId"); db.Class(typeof(Tag)); });
                         });
```

but this throws following exception

```
Could not determine type for:
System.Collections.Generic.IList[[Entities.IFaqTagReference,
BaseInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]],
mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, for
columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(FaqTagReferences)
```

thanks for every hint or solution

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c# nhibernate 3.2" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think might be something to do with liskovs substitution principle

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

```
essentially type IList<IFaqTagReference> is not type IList<FaqTagReference>
```

similar to 
[How do you map an entity -> interface relationship using Fluent NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022227/how-do-you-map-an-entity-interface-relationship-using-fluent-nhibernate)